# How to get a count of distinct max combinations - where the values in Column A and Column B BOTH need to be different than a previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my very first question on stack overflow - please be kind. :)
I'm hoping some SQL smarty pants out there can possibly point me in the right direction.

So for the sake of simplicity - we're dealing with two columns - Providers and Sites.

I'm supposed to only count rows when they are "two ***different*** providers at two ***different*** sites".

For example, let's say I have these two rows:

- Provider1, Site1
- Provider2, Site2

This would count as 2 - because they are two different providers, at two different sites.

Another example, let's say I have these two rows:

- Provider1, Site1
- Provider1, Site2

This would just count as 1, because distinction only occurs when they are two ***different*** providers at two ***different*** sites. So although there are two different sites - it's still the same provider.

The same goes the other way around - for example let's say I have these two rows:

- Provider1, Site1
- Provider2, Site1

This too would just count as 1, because distinction only occurs when they are two ***different*** providers at two ***different*** sites. So although there are two different providers - it's still the same the same site.

A more complex example - let's say I have these 5 rows:

- Provider1,   Site1
- Provider2,   Site1
- Provider3,   Site2
- Provider4,   Site2
- Provider5,   Site2

This would just count as 2. Following the logic where distinction only occurs when they are two ***different*** providers at two ***different*** sites. So although there are 5 different providers, there are only 2 different sites.

A more complicated example:

- Provider2,   Site1
- Provider2,   Site3
- Provider3,   Site2
- Provider4,   Site2
- Provider5,   Site2

This would only count as 2. Lines 1 and 2 are different sites, but the are the same provider. Since they are the same provider, that can only count as 1. As for lines 3 through 5, they are all different providers, but all the same site - so that can only count as 1. In total - the count should be 2.

I've tried using some count distinct methods, as well as dumping everything into a temp table and peeling away rows, all to no avail.

I am positive there is a better way I could asking this question but this is the best I can do for right now.

Can anyone suggest a method of how I can accomplish this count method in SQL?

Here's a sample temp table if needed:

```
    select * into #temp
from 
(
select 'Provider2' p,   'Site1' s 
union all select 'Provider2',   'Site3'
union all select 'Provider3',   'Site2'
union all select 'Provider4',   'Site2'
union all select 'Provider5',   'Site2'

) A

--Shows Sample
select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```

**Edit: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server**

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you using? Looks like SQL Server.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server - thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, we don't know which RDBMS you are using, but based on the syntax, I suspect SQL Server. If so, you can use the following query

**Query**

```
select  COUNT(*) + 1
from    (
        select  a.*, 
                case when a.p <> a.nextP then 1 else 0 end SameP, 
                case when a.s <> a.nextS then 1 else 0 end SameS 
        from    (   select  *, 
                            LEAD(p,1,NULL)OVER(ORDER BY p,s) nextP, 
                            LEAD(s,1,NULL)OVER(ORDER BY p,s) nextS 
                    from    #temp t
                ) a
    ) b
where SameP = 1 and SameS = 1
```

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server. I will try your above method. I never thought of using LEAD. I'll give it a try - thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which RDMS you are using but below query works in SQL Server and MY SQL:

```
select count(*)
  from (select t.*
        , Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY pg.pcnt ,ps.scnt ORDER BY t.p, t.s DESC) rno
        from temp t
         inner join (select p, count(*) pcnt from temp group by p) as pg on t.p = pg.p
         inner join (select s, count(*) scnt from temp group by s) as ps on t.s = ps.s
       ) gps
where gps.rno = 1
```

**Another way to do it in SQL server (and My SQL):**

```
select count(*)
from 
    (
        SELECT /*p, s
               ,*/
              distinct (count(p) over(partition by s) + count(s) over(partition by p)) cnt
        FROM #temp
    ) as gps
```

- SQL Server db fiddle can be found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=723d4ac79ca848b37c82702f2507658e)
- My SQL DB Fiddler can found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a1857fbfb5a0b062bbff93773eeab0f2)

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server. I'll also try out your above method - thank you so much for your help.